# Line not being drawn on all uitableviewcells

Tags: ios, uitableview, drawrect

I have a table view with a custom cell (governed by a custom class of course) that has the following `drawRect:` function in the custom class:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGRect busNumberFrame = busNumber.frame;

    NSLog(@"-----------------");
    NSLog(@"Line Origin X: %f", busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Line Origin Y: %f", self.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"Line End X: %f", busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Line End Y: %f", self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"-----------------");

    CGContextRef cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(cgContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cgContext, 0.75);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(cgContext, busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgContext, busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width, self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(cgContext);
}
```

This draws a line from the top of the cell to the bottom. This gets drawn successfully for the first cell but the subsequent cells don't show the line that's supposed to be drawn. Here is the code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BusInfoTableViewCell *cell = (BusInfoTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Bus Route Cell"];

    Bus *bus = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...

    cell.busNumber.text = [bus.number stringValue];
    cell.firstStop.text = bus.departure;
    cell.lastStop.text = bus.arrival;
    [cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];
    return cell;
}
```

And here is the log output of `drawRect:`:

```
2012-02-21 19:35:08.840 ETA[2208:707] -----------------
2012-02-21 19:35:08.843 ETA[2208:707] Line Origin X: 79.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.843 ETA[2208:707] Line Origin Y: 0.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.844 ETA[2208:707] Line End X: 79.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.845 ETA[2208:707] Line End Y: 63.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.845 ETA[2208:707] -----------------
2012-02-21 19:35:08.850 ETA[2208:707] -----------------
2012-02-21 19:35:08.851 ETA[2208:707] Line Origin X: 79.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.852 ETA[2208:707] Line Origin Y: 63.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.852 ETA[2208:707] Line End X: 79.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.853 ETA[2208:707] Line End Y: 126.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.853 ETA[2208:707] -----------------
2012-02-21 19:35:08.857 ETA[2208:707] -----------------
2012-02-21 19:35:08.857 ETA[2208:707] Line Origin X: 79.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.858 ETA[2208:707] Line Origin Y: 126.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.859 ETA[2208:707] Line End X: 79.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.859 ETA[2208:707] Line End Y: 189.000000
2012-02-21 19:35:08.860 ETA[2208:707] -----------------
```

I'm probably doing something wrong...

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay];` is not needed. It's the cell view, not its `contentView` property, that is affected by your `-drawRect:` method. The table view is automatically calling `-setNeedsDisplay` on your table view cell, so that's why it still works.

Comment: What is `busNumber`? Are you verifying that `-drawRect:` is being called multiple times with `NSLog` or breakpoints? What are the values you're trying to use for drawing that line at each iteration?

Comment: @LucasTizma even without `[cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay]` it was still drawing the line on the first cell only. I did set a break on the first line of `drawRect:` and it stopped various times there but I didn't see if `busNumber`was in fact pointing to a valid control. I'll have to see that when I get home from work tonight.

Comment: @LucasTizma I removed `[cell.contentView setNeedsDisplay]` and put a break inside `drawRect:` and it was called for all 3 cells. But only the line was drawn on the first cell. :(

Comment: I was just commenting that that line of code was unnecessary. It doesn't relate to your actual issue. Do some debugging and output some values in `-drawRect:`. I have a suspicion that your coordinates for drawing are incorrect.

Comment: I edited the post above to include the log output.

Comment: Are you on a retina display?? Else try line width of 1.0

Comment: Your log output shows that you are posing the question incorrectly, since `drawRect:` *is* being called for every cell (whereas in your question you claim it isn't).

Comment: @NSIntegerMax I am testing on an iPhone 4+ but the first cell gets the line drawn successfully. The other two don't.

Comment: @matt That was before when I thought it wasn't calling it. It didn't have that debug output before. The problem now is why the other two cells don't have the line drawn like in the first cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The coordinates are local for the cell, so you should be using the following (all instances of `self.frame` should be `self.bounds`):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    CGRect busNumberFrame = busNumber.frame;

    NSLog(@"-----------------");
    NSLog(@"Line Origin X: %f", busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Line Origin Y: %f", self.bounds.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"Line End X: %f", busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"Line End Y: %f", self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"-----------------");

    CGContextRef cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(cgContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cgContext, 0.75);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(cgContext, busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width, self.bounds.origin.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(cgContext, busNumberFrame.origin.x + busNumberFrame.size.width, self.bounds.origin.y + self.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextStrokePath(cgContext);
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I just need a way to remember when to use frame or bounds.

Comment: Bounds are used for what of your content is visible relative to the frame. Frame is used when you want to manipulate the position of objects.